# Does one show up on the enemy radar if he uses unsilenceable weapons in MW3?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

If he fires an RPG or M203, which do not have silencers, does he show up?

What about knifing? The knife doesn't have a silencer, so does that mean knifing gives away your position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firing the RPG and/or grenade launchers will cause you to show up on enemy radar.  It doesn't make any difference whether or not a silencer is an option for a weapon.  It's generally safe to assume that any primary or secondary weapon that doesn't have an equipped silencer will make you appear on enemy radar.

The knife, on the other hand, is always considered silenced, and will never make you show up on enemy radar.  Throwing knives are also "always silenced" - as are all lethal/tactical devices.